# Storing a socket connection within session data

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

On my site the pages that require encrypted data submissions (login,register,etc...) use url parameters to pass error messages. However other parts use socket.io to send the error message. I would like to make the code more consistent by using the same method. Is there anything wrong with storing the socket connection within session data? I haven't been able to find any other cases of people doing this.

Old method

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  if(bad_password){
    res.redirect('/login?message=Bad Password');
  }else{
    res.redirect('/home');
  }
}
```

New Method

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  if(bad_password){
    req.session.socket.emit('message','Bad password');
  }else{
    res.redirect('/home');
  }
}

io.on('connnection',function(socket){
  socket.handshake.session.socket = socket;
  socket.handshake.session.save();
}
```